# HuggingFace transformer evaluation process is too slow

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, training-data, huggingface

I used the HuggingFace `transformers` library to train a BERT model for sequence classification.

The training process is good on GPU, but the evaluation process(which is running GPU) is too slow. For example, when I just have a sanity check for just 20 short text inputs, the evaluation runtime is about 160 seconds per step.

Here's the snippet code:

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    accuracy_metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")
    f1_metric = evaluate.load("f1", average="macro")

    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

    accuracy = accuracy_metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)
    f1_score = f1_metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels, average="macro")

    return {**accuracy, **f1_score}
```

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        base_model_path,
        num_labels=num_labels,
        id2label=id2label,
        label2id=label2id
    )

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=".",
        learning_rate=lr,
        per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
        num_train_epochs=n_epoch,
        weight_decay=weight_decay,
        evaluation_strategy="steps",
        eval_steps=eval_steps,
        logging_strategy="steps",
        logging_steps=logging_steps,
        save_strategy="steps",
        save_steps=saving_steps,
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        report_to=["tensorboard"],
    )

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=tokenized_train_ds,
        eval_dataset=tokenized_valid_ds,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    )

    trainer.train()
```

The properties of the environment:

```
transformers              4.29.2
Python                    3.10.9
```

and the configuration of training is like the following:

```
len(train_data) ~= 36K
len(valid_data) ~= 2K
len(test_data) ~= 2K

model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'

per_device_train_batch_size=16
per_device_eval_batch_size=16
num_train_epochs=30
```

P.S.: The length of all data is small(less than ten tokens).

Can anyone suggest a solution to reduce the time overhead of the evaluation process?

Comment: You need to clarify the "too slow" part, what times are you talking about?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I added to the question. For example, for just 20 short text inputs, the evaluation runtime is about 160 seconds per epoch.

Comment: What is the output of `len(tokenized_valid_ds)`? And what is the `per_device_train_batch_size` and `per_device_eval_batch_size` you have used?

Comment: How did you initialize the tokenizer? And what is the max_length set for it?

Comment: BTW, is it 160 per epoch? or 160 per step of the optimizer?

Comment: To help us help you better, we'll need a little more information other than the ones posted in the above comments, esp. (i) what is the transformers library version? (ii) which model are you using and how large is it? and on which GPU/CPU are you running the code? (iii) how large is the validation dataset? (iv) how long are your inputs in trainng and evaluation? (iv) which dataset did you use to evaluate? and is it the same dataset as the training data?

Comment: @alvas I updated my question w.r.t your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got the problem. It's related to `evaluate.load()` calls inside the `compute_metrics` function. It seems this method has a significant overhead in time, so it shouldn't be inside some functions e.g. `compute_metrics` which are called many times. I moved out two `load()` methods of `compute_metrics` function and it works quickly now.